# Truncated incorrect date value: '2020-02-03 12:51:16'

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I'm trying to delete a lot of row from a table but I get a error anybody know about this

```
DELETE l,l2 from 
logprocesoitem l 
JOIN logproceso l2 ON l2.id=l.logproceso_id  
where  STR_TO_DATE(l2.createat,'%Y-%m-%d')< DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 MONTH);
```

[image]

Comment: What is the datatype of `createat`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `createat` field includes times, but the format in `STR_TO_DATE()` only allows for dates.

```
STR_TO_DATE(l2.createat,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

If you want to ignore the times, use the `DATE()` function on the result:

```
DATE(STR_TO_DATE(l2.createat,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'))
```

Comment: Str_to_date appears to be redundant here

Comment: True, since this happens to be the format that MySQL can parse automatically. OTOH, being explicit can make code clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the format `'%Y-%m-%d'` but your data is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'`.  But you shouldn't need STR_TO_DATE at all; just compare `l2.createat < DATE_SUB...`